# Are there examples of probability distributions $q(k), p(k)$ such that $\sum_{k} \log k^{q(k) - p(k)} < 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, analysis, inequality

Suppose $q(k), p(k)$ are two probability distributions on $k = 1,2,\dots$ such that $q(k) = \frac{kp(k)}{\sum_k kp(k)}$. Are there any explicit examples of $q(k), p(k)$ such that $\sum_{k =1}^ {\infty} \log k^{q(k) - p(k)} < 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such examples.  Note that

$$\sum_{k } \log k^{q(k) - p(k)}={1\over \sum_j jp(j)}\left(  \sum_{k}p(k)k\log k-\left(\sum_{j}p(j)j \right)\left( \sum_{k}p(k)\log k\right) \right),$$

so equivalently, you want to show $X$ and $\log X$ are negatively correlated, i.e.
$$\text{Cov}(X,\log X)=E[X\log X]-E[X]E[\log X]< 0\quad (1)$$

where the expectation is taken under the distribution $p$.  However, $(1)$ cannot hold since

$$\begin{align}\text{Cov}(X,\log X)&=E[X\log X]-E[E[X]\log X]\\
&=E[(X-E[X])\log X]\\
&=E[(X-E[X])\log X]-\underbrace{E[(X-E[X])\log E[X]]}_{=0}\\
&=E[(X-E[X])(\log X-\log E[X])]\geq 0,
\end{align}$$

where the inequality follows from the fact that $X\gtreqless E[X] \iff \log X\gtreqless \log E[X]$ since the log function is increasing.

Comment: I do not understand  your calculation of covariance, since $E(\log X)\neq \log E(X).$

Comment: @GérardLetac Correct but $E[(X-E[X])a]=0$ for constant $a$

Comment: @GérardLetac Added in a couple steps if it helps

Answer (score 1):

The ' example' is not correct since it does not provided the strict inequality. Actually such an  example cannot exist since $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(\log k)\, p_k\geq \left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\, p_k\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\log k)\, p_k\right)$$ To prove this we use the fact that $\log$ is an increasing function, implying that $u_{k,m}=(k-m)(\log k-\log m)\geq 0$. Therefore  $$\ 0\leq\sum_{k,m}u_{k,m}p_kp_m=2\left[\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(\log k)\, p_k-\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k\, p_k\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\log k)\, p_k\right)\right].$$ Equality occurs if and only if $p$ is concentrated on one point.